# Feature selection with linear interaction between variables and correlation with categorical response variable

Tags: feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction, mutual-information

I am searching for a feature selection algorithm able to select the minimum number (minimum redundancy) of relevant variables (maximum relevance) with respect to a categorical response variable.

I found mRMR [1] but I am unsure on how it behaves with variable interactions (I think it works better on single variables than on their combinations).

Specifically I am searching for an algorithm that is able to retain all variable that are relevant when linearly combined one with another (e.g. summing/subtracting their value). I cannot combine them first and then run mRMR afterwards since the number of combinations is huge.

[1] Peng, Hanchuan, Fuhui Long, and Chris Ding. "[Feature selection based on mutual information criteria of max-dependency, max-relevance, and min-redundancy](http://home.penglab.com/papersall/docpdf/2005_TPAMI_FeaSel.pdf)," IEEE Transactions on pattern analysis and machine intelligence 27.8 (2005): 1226-1238.

Comment: I don't know this method, and I doubt many do, but the paper says "Our scheme of mRMR does not intend to select features that are independent of each other. Instead, at each step, it tries to select a feature that minimizes the redundancy and maximizes the relevance. For real data, the features selected in this way will have more or less correlation with each other. However, our analysis and experiments show that the joint effect of these features can lead to very good classification accuracy." Why don't you just try it?

Comment: @Emre thanks for your comment, I tried it. So, do you interpret that sentence as that one combination of the variables could be selected by the algorithm? Because my interpretation was that mRMR selects features which are good *per se* and that taken together are good to classify better. However my problem, which I haven't proved that is equivalent, is that I need to select features which are relevant *when added/subtracted one with another*. In your opinion, is that the same problem?

Comment: @Emre what I am searching for is like this: http://www.nature.com/articles/srep30672 . I will try to use this (the paper was published last week)